# "object Object" or undefined returned while accessing JSON elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've parsed the json string and I am trying to access the elements. I am unable to access link1, link2, link3

```
{
"click_title":"GO",

"links":

    {

    "commonlink":"http:\/\/bookings.com",

    "alllinks":
        [
        [
            {

                "link1":"http:\/\/xyz1.com\/get\/a",

                "link2":"http:\/\/www.anotherwebsite1.com\/c\/t",

                "link3":"http:\/\/www.newsite1.com\/v\/h"
            },

            {

                "link1":"http:\/\/xyz2.com\/get\/a",

                "link2":"http:\/\/www.anotherwebsite2.com\/c\/t",

                "link3":"http:\/\/www.newsite2.com\/v\/h"

            }
        ],

        [
            {

                "link1":"http:\/\/xyz3.com\/get\/a",

                "link2":"http:\/\/www.anotherwebsite3.com\/c\/t",

                "link3":"http:\/\/www.newsite3.com\/v\/h"
            }
        ]
        ]
    }
}
```

var data = $.parseJSON(dbData);

I am able to access click_title and commonlink using this :-

```
data.click_title
data.links['commonlink']
```

but not able to access link1, link2, link3. 
I tried

```
data.links['alllinks'] which returns [object Object].
```

If I try

```
data.links['alllinks']['link1'] i get undefined
```

Comment: If you stop using alerts for debugging, and start using the console, you'll actually see the objects structure instead of `[object, object]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is very odd. `alllinks` is an array of arrays of objects (note the `[` and second `[` after `"alllinks":`, each of those starts an array). To get at the *first* `link1` in the *first* array, you'd do:

```
var link = data.links.alllinks[0][0].link1;
```

It's easier to see that if you format your JSON consistently. Here I've used http://jsonlint.com to clean it up, and then I've added some comments (not that comments are valid in JSON):

```
{
    "click_title": "GO",
    "links": {
        "commonlink": "http://bookings.com",
        "alllinks": [ // <== Starts the outer array
            [         // <== Starts an inner array
                {     // <== Starts the object that's the first entry
                    "link1": "http://xyz1.com/get/a",
                    "link2": "http://www.anotherwebsite1.com/c/t",
                    "link3": "http://www.newsite1.com/v/h"
                },
                {     // <== Starts the object that's the second entry
                    "link1": "http://xyz2.com/get/a",
                    "link2": "http://www.anotherwebsite2.com/c/t",
                    "link3": "http://www.newsite2.com/v/h"
                }
            ],        // <== Ends the first inner array
            [         // <== Starts the second inner array
                {
                    "link1": "http://xyz3.com/get/a",
                    "link2": "http://www.anotherwebsite3.com/c/t",
                    "link3": "http://www.newsite3.com/v/h"
                }
            ]         // <== Ends the second inner array
        ]             // <== Ends the outer array
    }
}
```

So in total, you have three `link1`'s: The one on the object at `[0][0]`, the one on the object at `[0][1]`, and the one on the object at `[1][0]`.